# Check If a user belong to a group In views

Tags: python, django, django-views

I want to check if a user belong to either `'onetime'` group or `'monthtime'` group in views.py so they can publish a post. I submitted a form using a user account that does not belong to any of the two groups, yet I was able to submit a post successfully. Instead it should tell me that I'm not eligible.

Models.py

```
class Emov(models.Model):
    user=models.ForeignKey(User)
    name=models.CharField(max_length=10)
    #otherfields
```

views.py

```
def e_hit(request):
    if request.method=="POST":
       form=EmovForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
       if form.is_valid():
           one=Group.objects.filter(name='onetime')
           month=Group.objects.filter(name='monthtime')
           if request.user in one or month:
               data=form.cleaned_data
               newesell=Emov(
                    user=request.user,
                    pub_date=datetime.datetime.now(),
                    name=data['name'])
               newpos.save()
               return HttpResponseRedirect('/approval/')
            else:
               return HttpResponse('You are not eligible')
         else:
            return HttpResponse('Fill the form')
      else:
         return render_to_response('post.html',{'EmovForm':EmovForm},context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Try this, which should save you some hits on the database as well as being more readable:

```
request.user.groups.filter(name__in=['onetime','monthtime']).exists()
```

Comment: Thanks it works! How about if I want to remove the user in 'onetime' group immediately after posting? Like under newpos.save()

Comment: Well, that's really a different question. I'm not sure that `auth.groups` is the way you want to handle this, but maybe it is. `g = Group.objects.get(name='onetime') 
g.user_set.remove(request.user)`.

Answer (score 2):

I think `if request.user in one or month:` should be `if request.user in one or request.user in month:`.

Answer (score 0):

Dont' forget to call the user set. Right now I think your code will compare the `request.user` with the groups rather than the users in them. Either:

```
if request.user in one.user_set.all() or reguest.user in month.user_set.all()
```

or

```
if one in request.user.groups.all() or month in request.user.groups.all()
```

should do what you need.

Comment: Scratch my answer, Rob L's is better.